# In-memory unmarshalling, from an XML string and its schema stored in a string too, possible?

Tags: java, in-memory, unmarshalling

Let's suppose I store an XML string into a variable

```
String resp = new String("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encodin...");
```

and the schema definition related to this XML in another one:

```
String xsd = new String("<xs:schema xmlns="http://schema-...");
```

do you think there is a way to validate and unmarshall 'resp'
into objects (using JAXB for example) ?? Has anybody already
tried or successfully implemented such stuff ??

In advance, thanks a lot for any suggestion...
Seb

Comment: Does this schema is known before compile-time? Or is it generated/obtained in a dynamic way?

Comment: I guess I would be interested in both: already having the jar file of all compiled classes coming from this protocol, and not knowing these classes in advance (I'm trying to see if I can implement a web service client, with the required XSD being inlined within the WSDL).
Thanks.

Comment: Please keep https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers in mind.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [unmarshal(Source source)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#unmarshal%28javax.xml.transform.Source%29) and [setSchema(Schema schema)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html#setSchema%28javax.xml.validation.Schema%29) of the Unmarshaller class. This should work:

```
unmarshaller.setSchema(SchemaFactory.newSchema(new StreamSource(new StringReader(xsd));
unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(resp));
```

Comment: Waow, very interesting indeed. I was looking at the wrong version of Unmarshaller this morning:
http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/api/javax/xml/bind/Unmarshaller.html
which has no setSchema() method...